# Issues with Rmarkdown chunks slow code execution in Rstudio

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

This has happend many times that after working for awhile on `Rmarkdown` files it tends to `slow or delay execution` of code chunks even when nothing else is running in Rtudio and the green color process bar appears dull with the clock symbol on execution.

[image]

Both **CPU and RAM** doesn't seems to be completely exhausted and still getting issues of slow execution of code.

To fix this I generally restart Rstudio.

And this happens even with smallest type of task as well.

Any idea what's wrong with it and how can I fix this issue or just improve ?

I am using windows 7